# How many pages are initialled for the first time in PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have created pages in Android by using `PagerAdapter`. When I tried to get value in the third page from EditText, I got `NullPointerException`.

In the third fragment page, I have initialled that EditText already.

```
    iName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

So does this problem occur while the third page haven´t initialled?

Comment: try to set mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit( pages count);

Answer (score 3):

A `ViewPager`, by default, keeps one fragment on each side in memory. You can change this by setting the offscreen page limit.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)):

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
>   of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in
>   place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in
>   perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have
>   a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once,
>   less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as
>   the user pages back and forth.
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex
>   layouts. This setting defaults to 1.
>
> Parameters limit  How many pages will be kept offscreen in an idle
>   state.

Example usage: `yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the default implementation of setOffscreenPageLimit() it is only loading the one fragment which is to the right of it. For eg. when you are on index 1, it has index 2 loaded in memory but not index 0, so swiping left will have to generate a new fragment from scratch. To test this theory you might want to use setOffscreenPageLimit(2) and then try swiping index 1->0. This in no way is the optimal solution but will help clear out your doubts about the concept.

Answer (score 0):

you can  store the fragment state of all the pages in the pages adaper like this and get reference of it.

**`PagerAdapter`**

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> fragmentsList;
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
Fragment fragment=new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
fragmentsList.add(fragment, position);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
public static List<Fragment> getFragmentsList(){
return fragmentsList;
}
    }
```

**In Activity:**

```
List<Fragment> fragList=adapter.getFragmentsList()
View view = fragList.get(position).getView();
if (view !=null) {
view.findViewById(R.id.text_view).setText("Child Accessed :D");
}
```